# Background Image not scaling on iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, scaling

I'm using Bootstrap to create my site: [www.nickvdesign.com](http://www.nickvdesign.com)

I was hoping that it would scale the background-image perfectly on both Android and iOS devices, but, there has been a slight problem. For all android devices, my site's background image scales perfectly, but when you try on any iPhone (4, 4S, 5) you only see a slight partition of the original image's top left-hand corner. (Which means it's not scaling properly.)

The CSS for the background-image is included below:

```
    #home {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    background:url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```